# hide on word and activate checkbox button

Tags: php, html

**I wrote a php/html website and I have to add two more things on it..**

- Program shouldn’t display extras in case the user didn’t choose any of the extra tasks options.
- If the **save this details checkbox** is ticked and the Calculate Salary is clicked, the details (total salary, extras, date and time) should be stored in one cookie that expires in 1 week. This cookie should be able to store history of the salary calculations in one cookie.

and this is my program:

```html
<html>

<body>
<?php
$none=0;
$cookie_name='historyDetails';
$cookie_value='[]';
$message='';
                    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bahrain');
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30) , "/");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if (isset($_POST['calculate_salary']))
    {
        // get all value of form in post variable
        $details=$_POST;
        $basic=0;
        $extra_tags='';
        // if basic salary is not given set zero
        if(isset($details['basic'])&& !empty($details['basic']))
        {
            $basic=$details['basic'];
        }
        $extra=[];
        // if extra values are unchecked the set as empty else add values
        if (isset($details['extra']))
        {
            foreach ($details['extra'] as $value)
            {
                // split extra value by hash
                $temp=explode("#",$value);
                // create associative array for future operations
                $extra[(integer)$temp[0]]=$temp[1];
                // for printing the list
                $extra_tags=$extra_tags.'<li>'.$temp[1].'</li>';
            }

        }

        // set BD according to their material status else zero
        $BD=0;
        switch($details['ms'])
        {
            case 'single':
                $BD=50;

                    break;
            case 'married':
                $BD=100;
        }
        // calculate total
        $total=$basic+array_sum(array_keys($extra))+$BD;
        // store cookies
        $cookie_values=(array)json_decode($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
        $history_value=['basic'=>$basic,'extra_sum'=>$extra,'ms'=>$BD,'total'=>$total,'date'=>date("Y-m-d"),'time'=> date("h:i:sa")];
        array_push($cookie_values,$history_value);
        setcookie($cookie_name, json_encode($cookie_values), time() +(86400 * 30), "/");
        // Generate html for display

        $message='<br/><br/><br/><ul>
            <li>Salary Details: Total Salary is BD '.(string)$total.'</li>
            <li>Extras:</li>
                <ol>
                '.$extra_tags.'
                </ol>
            <u1>';

    }

    elseif (isset($_POST['view_history'] ))
    {

        $histories=(array)json_decode($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
        $history_data='';
        foreach ($histories as $history)
        {
            $history=(array)$history;
            $extra_value='';
            foreach((array)$history['extra_sum'] as $extra)
            {
                $extra_value=$extra_value.'<li>'.$extra.'</li>';
            }
            $history_data=$history_data.'
                <li> Date: '.(string)$history['date'].' Time: '.(string)$history['time'].'<br/>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Salary Details: Total Salary is BD <b>'.(string)$history['total'].'</b> </li>
                    <li>Extras: </li>
                        <ol>
                        '.$extra_value.'
                        </ol>
                    </ul>
                </li><br/>';
        }
        $message='<br/>
            <h3>History details of your old salary calculations</h3><br/><br/>
            <ol>'.$history_data.'</ol>';
    }
}
?>
    <form method='post' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        Basic Salary <input type='number' name='basic' /><br />

        Marital Status: <br />
        <input type='radio' name='ms' value='single' checked /> Single <br />
        <input type='radio' name='ms' value='married' /> Married <br />

        Extra: <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name="extra[]" value="200#Work on Weekend" /> Work on Weekend - BD 200<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name="extra[]" value="100#Work Night Shift" /> Work Night Shift - BD 100<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name="extra[]" value="400#Work Abroad" />  Work Abroad - BD 400<br />


        <br /><br />
        <input type='checkbox' name="save"    value="historyDetails" /> save this details<br />
        <br />


        <input type='submit' name='calculate_salary' value='Calculate Salary' />

        <input type='submit' name='view_history' value='View History' />

    </form>

  <?php echo($message); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This site is not a code-writing nor code-review service, you should write minimal reproducible example of specific question or problem.

Extras:
you have to simply check if the extras are present or not, for simple example check if variable contains something:

```
$history_data = '<ul><li>...</li>'.($extra_value?'<li>Extras:</li> <ol>'.$extra_tags.'</ol>':'').'</ul>';
```

or

```
$message = '<ul><li>...</li>'.($extra_tags?'<li>Extras:</li><ol>'.$extra_value.'</ol>':'').'</ul>';
```

Cookies: when you output any text, the header was already sent, so you cannot perform any php functions which manipulate the header anymore, more specifically: `<html><body>` this has to be written after `setcookie`. You are doing `setcookie` of the same cookie-name multiple times, so you are sending it twice (in case of form submit), it will still work but you should know about that. On line 10 `setcookie` is absolutely unnecessary, it overwrite the value to empty json array.

Saving cookie when 'save' is checked: at the place where you have `// store cookies` put block: `if(isset($_POST['save'])){ ... setcookie(...); }` checkboxes are not sent when they are not checked so this is enough.

One more thing: `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` this is unnecessary, default action is self by default, in case you still want it there put there second parameter `ENT_QUOTES` because its html attribute value not between tags.